# Join on 3 tables

Tags: sql, join, sybase

i have currently 3 tables :

- Table A
- Table B
- Table C

There is a link between A & B and a link between B & C (A-B-C).
The thing is that :

- It is possible to have a row in A but no not in B
- It is possible to have a row in B but not in A
- It is possible to have a row in B but not in C

In the end i would like to have a query which could give me the following row (where X represent the ID of the corresponding table) :

```
TableA|TableB|TableC
   X  |   X  |   X
   X  | null | null 
 null |   X  |   X
   X  |   X  | null
```

I managed to have the case with TableA & TableB with the following query :

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID
FROM TABLEA A
LEFT JOIN TABLEB B on (join condition)
UNION
SELECT A.ID,B.ID
FROM TABLE B
LEFT JOIN TABLEA A on (join condition)
```

Thank you for any help you may provide

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, however, you have tagged your post with [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase) - it depends what you mean by that.  Sybase ASE doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN` syntax, but SQL Anywhere does.

Comment: Nice info... :) I have not worked on Sybase and it seems I have to modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly then a `FULL OUTER JOIN` should do your work :

```
SELECT a.id,b.id,c.id
FROM   TableA a 
       FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b on a.id = b.id
       FULL OUTER JOIN TableC c on COALESCE(a.id,b.id) = c.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3a4d/2)